# Automatically opening a URL in an Excel Document, each time one is generated

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have an excel document with multiple rows/columns, with the final column being a URL that is generated (using data from the previous columns).

As new rows are added/filled out, a new URL is generated for each Row.

I am trying to figure out how to write a VBA script which will automatically open each URL/hyperlink as it is created or edited.

I have tried a few different scripts online however have not had any luck.

Comment: You can Try `Worksheet_Change` event to capture the change in cell with URL and open it once it changes.

Comment: Right, so perhaps Worksheet_Change > Open most recent URL (i.e. URL on the most recent Row)?

I'm not sure how to go about that

Comment: Yes Exactly like that

Comment: Do you have any resources you could direct me to, on how to write this in VBA?

Comment: Exactly how is the URL being generated?

Comment: Read [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) for Worksheet Change Event

Comment: Use this to open the HyperLink `Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Follow`

Comment: @TimWilliams it is being generated by basically stringing together different components, held in seperate columns. For example, column A has "www.example.com/", column B has a first name like "John", column C has a surname like "Smith".

Column D is the column which pieces it together, so A2&B2&C2, resulting in www.example.com/john/smith .

The names are entered via a seperate form, with a new row for each client.

Comment: @Mikku assuming the URLs are held in column D, is there any chance you could show an example code on how to structure it?